# Filter the Pyspark Dataframe between two dates

Tags: date, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe as below. I need the rows only target_date between 2017-12-17 and 2017-12-19 both the dates are included.
Input:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|target_date|order_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1471783| 2017-12-16|           2|
|1471885| 2017-12-16|           2|
|1472928| 2017-12-17|           2|
|1476917| 2017-12-17|           2|
|1477469| 2017-12-18|           1|
|1478190| 2017-12-19|           4|
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Output that I need is like below.

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     id|target_date|order_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1472928| 2017-12-17|           2|
|1476917| 2017-12-17|           2|
|1477469| 2017-12-18|           1|
|1478190| 2017-12-19|           4|
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use the `between`.

```
df.filter("target_date between '2017-12-17' and '2017-12-19'").show(truncate=False)

+-------+-----------+------------+
|id     |target_date|order_before|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|1472928|2017-12-17 |2           |
|1476917|2017-12-17 |2           |
|1477469|2017-12-18 |1           |
|1478190|2017-12-19 |4           |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another doubt, how can I get the maximum date, minimum  date in target_date column.

Comment: datatype of target_date is timestamp.

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max

df.select(min("target_date"), max("target_date")).first()